# How to get url path from images,font,etc in css files?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I try get this from css files:

```
url(/myServer/img/mosaico.png)
```

and I try with this:

```
preg_match_all('/url\((["\']?)((?!["\']?[data:]?).*?\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|woff|eot|ttf))\\1\)?/i', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER))
```

But it not works property,the expression only captures some occurrences. What is the problem?

I also need to get the parts in brackets in regular expresion, like this:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => 'url(/img/arrow-top-white.png)',
    (int) 1 => '',
    (int) 2 => '/img/arrow-top-white.png',
    (int) 3 => 'png'
)
```

Comment: Why you used  a negated character class?

Comment: Why you fail to do simply like this http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/19 ?

Comment: I get some of the regular expression on internet, I do not understand any of the negatives that appear, sorry

Comment: did the above link works for you?

Comment: @AvinashRaj A very useful website, thank you very much

Comment: Yep, it's a nice site to check regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  the below regex to match all the strings which are mentioned above.

```
url\(((?:\/[^\/()]+?)+?\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|woff|eot|ttf))[^)]*\)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/39)

```
<?php
$content = "url(/myServer/img/mosaico.png)";
preg_match_all('~url\(((?:\/[^\/]+)+\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|woff|eot|ttf))\)~', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => url(/myServer/img/mosaico.png)
            [1] => /myServer/img/mosaico.png
            [2] => png
        )

)
```

Comment: yes it works, but I need to try to get the parts in the parentheses

Comment: That does not work properly, do not get the extension of the file(not very important) but only finds two occurrences

Comment: It return this: (int) 0 => array(
  (int) 0 => 'url(/img/bodyTexture.png)',
  (int) 1 => /img/bodyTexture.png'
 ),
 (int) 1 => array(
  (int) 0 => 'url(/img/mosaico.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    color:#fff;
    background-size:cover;

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/22 . If you have further queries then edit your question and add the expected output.

Comment: thanks for your time, i added the output that i expect in question. I therefore positively rated yourresponse, but is not the solution that i need :)

Comment: why you want the second one as empty?

Comment: The last regex that you put get all parts that i need, but it not work correctly. Test your expresion with this text : url(/var/www/synergicNetwork/app/webroot/img/mosaico.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    color:#fff;
    background-size:cover;
url(/var/www/synergicNetwork/app/webroot/img/mosaico.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    color:#fff;
    background-size:cover;

Comment: It works, only fails with this string url(/ghfdgh/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff)

Comment: here http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/25 . I think you don't want to match the url string which has no extensions.

Comment: it is that I needed '/url\(((?:\/[^\/()]+?)+?\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg|woff|eot|ttf))[^)]*\)/im'it similar yours but not the same, edit your answer and I accept a close this  :-). And really thanks

Comment: updated... I thought that you don't want to match the url if it's don't have the exact extension.